# Laravel AdminLTE y Entrust-gui error de Route::group

Tags: laravel, login

Tengo un error en el enroutado de Laravel estoy usando AdminLTE como diseño y Entrust para el control de nivel de usuario pero quiero que cuando login como admin se redirija a otra routa que esta en el AdminController y con el usuario igual para tener todo bien controllado y evitar el código espagueti que se haría si lo hago todo con @role

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {   
//    Route::get('/link1', function ()    {
   // Uses Auth Middleware   });

//Please do not remove this if you want adminlte:route and adminlte:link commands to works correctly.
#adminlte_routes    
   });

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
   Route::get('/home', 'AdminController@index');       });

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:user']], function() {
Route::get('/home', 'UserController@index');        });
```

cuando uso una de los route::group de role:admin o  role:user empieza a dar errores el login y logout dan error al tratar de ir a la pagina /home (pagina de inicio de los 2 controller), pero si vuelvo a la pagina principal el (index) esta logeado la cuenta.

[image: Esta es la imagen del error que da]

En esencia es que no puedo tener esos 2 Route::group y por cuestiones de orden es necesario usarlos

Comment: ¿podemos ver el listado de rutas?

Comment: Realmente eso es todo en cuanto rutas soy nuevo en laravel y quería comenzar solo haciendo un login que diferenciara entre roles y el admin creara usuarios ( con estrust ya esta listo) y ahora solo queria incorporar lo estrust a adminlte, no e hecho mas nada que instalar adminlte, implementar estrust y hacer las migraciones